# Why Python return 'None'

Tags: python, list

```
'''

  function 'text_strip_split(text)' delete special symbolsand
  whitespace in start and end string,after we enter number of word ,
  that it should write , and finally write this word.

'''

def text_strip_split(text):

    list = [ '!' , ',' , '.' , '?' , ':' , '/' , '*' , '#' , '%' , '\\' , '_' , '-' , '=' , '+' , '&' ,';']

    for i in list:
        text = text.replace( i  , ' ').strip()
    text = text.split()

    print()

    while True:
        x = int(input('Enter number word that i should print on console:\n')) - 1
        if x > len(list) or x < 0:
            print('Enter other number!')
        else:
            break

    print(text[x])


word = input('Write the something text with special symbols: \n')
print(text_strip_split(word))
```

Comment: Because there's no `return` statement.

Comment: Please ,tell my how you can simplify or combine my 'list' ?

Comment: @chepner I appreciate that you deleted your answer when you closed, lots out there that don't

Comment: Your `text_strip_split` function doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no return statement in the function.

Comment: Can we help me? How you can combine or simplify my list with special symbols? May be Python have got a something function or module with them?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor you may want to look at string.punctuation. It contains all the ASCII punctuation symbols.